# Code doesn't work (isset checkbox foreach)

Tags: php

I have problem because i use loop "while" to loading database information about ID Domains and domains_name. Next I do input check box because i want delete domain when i isset check box. I do loop "foreach" but this code works only one records. How can I change code to works more records

```
<?php 
$result = $connect->query("SELECT * FROM domains where id_person='$id_person'");
$how_nick = $result->num_rows;

if ($how_nick != 0) {
    while($data = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
?> 
<tr class="staff">
    <td class="staff">
    Nazwa Domeny:<br> 
        <input class="staff" type="text" value="<?php echo $data['domain_name']; ?>" name="domain_name[]" placeholder="<?php echo $data['domain_name']; ?>" onfocus="this.placeholder='<?php echo $data['domain_name']; ?>'" onblur="this.placeholder='<?php echo $data['domain_name']; ?>'"/><br />
    </td>

    <td class="staff">Usuń:<br> 
        <input type="checkbox" name="id[]" value="<?php echo $data['id'];?>"/>
    </td>
</tr>
<?php            
}}}}
?>
```

more code to loop "foreach"

```
if(isset($_POST['send'])) {
    $all_ok=true;
    $id = $_POST['id']; 
    $domain_name = $_POST['domain_name']; 
    foreach ($domain_name as $key => $value) 
    {
        if((preg_match('/[ćęłńóśźżA\/]/',$value)) || (!preg_match('/[.]/',$value)))
        {
            $all_ok=false;
            $score="Formuła domeny".' <b> '.$value.' </b> '. "jest nie poprawna!".'<br>';   
        }else{
            $result = $connect->query("SELECT id FROM domains WHERE domain_name='$value' AND id_person != '$id_person'");

            if (!$result) throw new Exception($connect->error);

                $how_domain_name = $result->num_rows;
                if($how_domain_name>0) {
                    $all_ok=false;
                    $score="Istnieje już domena".' <b> '.$value.' </b> '.'<br>';

                }       
            }

            foreach ($id as $key => $value) {
                if(isset($value)){
                    $score=$value;
                }
            }

            if ($all_ok==true) {
                $count = count($id); 
                for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++) {
                    $connect->query('UPDATE domains 
                            SET domain_name="'.$domain_name[$i].'" 
                            WHERE id='.(int)$id[$i].'');
                }
                if(!empty($delete_domain)){
                    $connect->query('DELETE FROM domains WHERE id='.$value.'');
                }
                $_SESSION['well_done']=true;
                header('Location: change_data_confirm.php');
            }
        }
```

Comment: Your script is open to [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php). 
Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string)
You should consider using [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) in either the `MYSQLI_` or `PDO` API's instead of concatenated values

Answer (score 0):

One reason is you are overriding $key, $value variable in inner loop-

```
 foreach ($id as **$key => $value**) {
            if(isset($value)){
                $score=$value;
            }
        }
```

I think this is the issue.